# Where is a database shape in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, shapes

I am trying to document an architecture in Visio, and I can't find a shape for a database. I see servers, clients, etc. - but no database.

Comment: Please consider marking the more upvoted question the correct answer.

Comment: I actually did a search for databases in the shapes column and was presented with many different database designs. I'm using Microsoft Visio Standard 2010.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I think the user was asking about finding a database stencil, rather than looking to generate a Visio document for an existing database.

If that is correct, I believe the desired shape can be found under:

**File -> Shapes -> Flowchart -> Miscellaneous Flowchart Shapes**

Source:
  https://web.archive.org/web/20120121234844/http://www.workplacelife.com/2006/04/11/creating-flowcharts-using-common-visio-shapes

P.S. Sorry for posting to an old thread, but Google brought me here with a similar question and, once I found the answer, I thought I would share.

Comment: nothing wrong posting to an old thread

Comment: Nothing wrong considering this it THE answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why would such common object, understood by many, be embedded in such obscure place/menu?!

Comment: Yep, four years later, someone else is again grateful that you wrote your answer.

Comment: Looks like that link is now broken.

Answer (score 8):

Which version do you have? Because it's not included in all version.

- **Standard** :  This edition does not include the Database Model Diagram template.
- **Professional**:   This edition supports the reverse engineering features for the Database Model Diagram template (that is, using an existing database to create a model in Visio) but does not support forward engineering (that is, using a Visio database model to generate SQL code).
- **Enterprise Architect**:   This edition, which is included in Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 Enterprise Architect, supports the full suite of database modeling features, including both reverse engineering and forward engineering.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HA011496971033.aspx)

Comment: The Source link in this one is broken as well.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 7):

On Visio 2010, there is a Database relational shape in Network - Network Symbols. In italian, Altre forme -  Rete - Simboli Rete . There is a Database relational shape that is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Can also be found under `Shapes -> Software & Database -> Software -> Common Icons`.

Comment: My Visio 2007 doesn't have a "Common Icons" option under Shapes -> Software & Database -> Software.

Comment: You forgot to specify the version you are using.  I assumed you were using 2010.

Comment: The Software & Database category is available in Visio Pro only, not Visio Standard.

Comment: im using 2016, and it worked perfectly fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a basic, upright cylinder:

Shapes -> Software and Database -> Software -> Enterprise Application

The shape is titled "Datastore".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative: http://www.itsupportforum.net/topic/where-to-find-the-database-shape-in-visio-2010/

There's an option of a grey or white database shape here.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.