# Visio 2010 Professional No Database Tab

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I am trying to create a ERD using VISIO Professional 2010 (full install) but I am having problems.

1. I can't open the table properties windows at the bottom of the screen when I double click on a table, and I can't right-click on the table and choose properties because the choice is not there...
2. The Database tab is missing from the ribbon on top.

What can cause this? Here is what I already tried:
`File/Options/Trust Center/ Trust Center Settings.../Add-ins/Disable all Application Add-ins` is UNCHECKED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2...I managed to find this thread from the Microsoft TechNet forums that discusses this: [Visio 2010 Professional No Database Tab](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visiogeneral/thread/7f74a980-d643-47af-8053-6b7107a8abad/)

From the post:

> If you still don't see the Database tab on the ribbon in a new
>   Database Model Diagram go to File/Options/Trust Center/ Trust Center
>   Settings.../Add-ins/Disable all Application Add-ins (may impair
>   functionality) is unchecked.

And I apologize for my first answer.  Somehow I read "Visual Studio" instead of Visio.

Comment: I already tried that, it's already unchecked.

Comment: Which edition of Visio 2010 do you have?  There's a related post that explains why this is important: http://superuser.com/questions/108534/where-is-a-database-shape-in-visio ...unless that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: I am running Visio Professional 2010 version 14.0.4760.1 (32-bits)